# Find any array of length N with standard deviation K

Tags: statistics, computer-science, standard-deviation, variance

This problem was asked on ACM ICPC 2018 preliminary round. You have to print any array of length **N** whose standard deviation is K.

Comment: Hint: Given an array with K elements, it's possible to extend it to arbitrary length by adding elements with a specific value such that nor the mean nor the variance change.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention constraints on data types, so I assume you are OK with floating-point results (the alternative is that you want integer-only solutions, and if that is the intent then the below is woefully inadequate to that task.)

Over the reals, we expect that given an array of length `n-1` with standard deviation `k'`, we should be able to derive an array of length `n` with standard deviation `k > k'` by adding some element to the shorter array. That is, by adjusting the new element, we can sweep continuously over all values starting at `k` and going on up.

With this observation, we might guess we can start with any nominal array - say, `[0, 0, ..., 0]` of length `n - 1`, and add some element to it to make the standard deviation "come out" right. Let's call the value to be added `v`. The mean of such an array would be:

```
m = (0 + 0 + ... + 0 + v) / n = v/n
```

The variance would be:

```
s^2 = [(0-m)^2 + (0-m)^2 + ... + (0-m)^2 + (v-m)^2] / n
```

We can substitute in the expression for the mean:

```
s^2 = [(v/n)^2 + (v/n)^2 + ... + (v/n)^2 + (v-v/n)^2] / n
```

We can factor out a `v^2` term:

```
s^2 = v^2[(1/n)^2 + ... + (1/n)^2 + (1-1/n)^2] / n
```

We can replace the repeated addition with multiplication:

```
s^2 = v^2 [(n-1)(1/n)^2 + (1-1/n)^2] / n
```

Finally, we can solve for `v` to see what we add to our array:

```
v = s / sqrt([(n-1)(1/n)^2 + (1-1/n)^2] / n)
```

Some algebra shows this simplifies to:

```
v = s * n / sqrt(n - 1)
```

Recall we are given `s = k`, so by substituting in we can determine `v`:

```
v = k * n / sqrt(n - 1)
```

The resulting array will contain `n - 1` zeroes and one `v`.

Example: `k = 1, n = 10`:

```
v = 1 * 10 / sqrt(9) = 10/3
m = 1/3
s = sqrt((9*(1/3)^2 + (10/3-1/3)^2)/10)
  = sqrt((9(1/9) + (9/3)^2)/10)
  = sqrt((1 + 9)/10)
  = sqrt(10/10) = 1
```